# Edge border for navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, border

I have a fairly simple navigation bar with a bottom border but I would like to box it off on either side - but not the top. So I get a |______________| surrounding all of my links but I am just starting out and whatever I try seems to border every single link which I don't want.

```
<nav>
    <div align="center">
    <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
       <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
       <li><a href="/careers">Careers</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!--navigation-->
</nav>
```

and css

```
nav { 
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;     
}
nav ul li {
  width: 16.6%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  color: #202020;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro Light";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color:  #89ccca
}
nav ul{
  width: 80%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `first-child` and `last-child` properties and apply it like below.

**CSS**

```
 nav ul li:first-child
 {
   border-left: 1px solid #A2A2A2; 
 }
 nav ul li:last-child
 {
   border-right: 1px solid #A2A2A2; 
 }
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/na9s50hy/)

Comment: Fab! thank you so much. Only issue now is it doesn't reach the top of the page but I will play around with positioning.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i can help you

try this

```
    nav ul li {
width: 16.0%;
float: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
border-right: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
}

nav ul li:first-child{border-left: 1px solid #A2A2A2;}
```

fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/zfdxko8h/

Answer (score 0):

try including this one..

```
#navigation ul li:first-child { 
    border-left: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}
#navigation ul li:last-child { 
    border-right: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}
```

[Here is The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j45xj7xn/1/)